# Does pg_typeof ever return alternative type names?

Tags: postgresql

**For context:**
I have a sql function that takes an array of strings. Those strings are sql expressions that are stored in a table and used some time later for dynamically creating some queries.
I want to restrict the data types of those expressions to some limited set. For that I intend to evaluate the expressions and check the data type with pg_typeof like so:

```
create function fun(expressions text[]) returns void as $$
declare
  expression_type text;
begin
  for i in 1..array_length(expressions, 1) loop
    execute format('select pg_typeof((select %s from some_table where false))', expressions[i]) into expression_type ;
    -- check that expression_type has legal value, raise exception otherwise
  end loop;
  -- store expressions for later use
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

For example suppose that `integer` and `timestamp without time zone` are the allowed types.
I'd like to list the allowed types in an enum:

```
create type supported_types as enum ('integer', 'timestamp with time zone');
```

For some types PostgreSQL documentatsion also mentions alternative names, e.g `int4` instead of `integer`, `timestamp` instead of `timestamp without time zone` etc.

**My queston is** that do I have to worry about these "alternative names" for types when I enumerate the ones I care about?
I.e if I include `integer` do I also have to include `int4` or in other words does `pg_typeof` ever return `int4` instead of `integer` (or `timestamp` instead of `timestamp without time zone` etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not.

Function internally ([C code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/misc.c#L634)) returns `OID`, but since in PostgreSQL it is declared as returning `regtype`, it is cast to it. Since OID is the same regardless of name/alias for type, it will always give the same result.

```
postgres=# SELECT 'int4'::regtype::oid::regtype;
 regtype
---------
 integer
(1 row)
```